# DotNet and Ionic API performance

Tags: asp.net, angular, performance, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

So i have this code in the backend which fetches data from the Redis cache since it is cached everytime someone clicks the link from the webpage, here is the code for that

```
 [Route("story/filter"), AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(StoryModel))]
        [WebApiAuth(MinimumRole = RoleType.Reader, EntityType = ChannelRoleEntityType.Channel)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FilterStories([FromBody] StoryFilterModel filterModel)
        {   
            int iUserId = _userSession.CurrentUser.UserId;
            bool bIsFiltered = false;
            if (filterModel.SWOT?.Length > 0 || filterModel.DateRange?.Length > 0 ||
                filterModel.DocumentType?.Length > 0 || filterModel.CommentType?.Length > 0 ||
                (filterModel.Q.Length > 0 && !filterModel.Q.Equals("*")) || filterModel.freeTextSearch?.Length > 0)
            {
                bIsFiltered = true;
            }         
                if ((CacheManager.Instance.IsDataSaved(CacheKey.ChannelList + "_" + filterModel.ChannelID + "_" + filterModel.Page)) && !bIsFiltered)
                {
                    var results = CacheManager.Instance.GetData<StoryServiceResponseModel>(CacheKey.ChannelList + "_" + filterModel.ChannelID + "_" + filterModel.Page);
                    var result = _mapper.Map<StoryModel>(results);
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    var storyRequest = _mapper.Map<StoryServiceRequestModel>(filterModel);
                    var results = await _dataService.GetStories(storyRequest);
                    var searchResults = _channelService.GetStoriesWithAttachmentFlags(results.SearchResults.ToList<StoryResponseModel>());
                    if (filterModel.SendStoryId != null)
                        results.SearchResults = searchResults.DistinctBy(story => story.UniqueID).ToList();
                    else
                        results.SearchResults = searchResults.ToList();
                    if (!bIsFiltered)
                    {
                        CacheManager.Instance.SaveData<StoryServiceResponseModel>(CacheKey.ChannelList + "_" + filterModel.ChannelID + "_" + filterModel.Page, results, 30, ExpiryTimeUnit.Minutes);
                    }
                    var result = _mapper.Map<StoryModel>(results);
                    return Ok(result);
                }
        }
```

Now When I try to open the same page from mobile (ios Application) build with Ionic and Angular, the app takes too much time to load up,
Here is the code from the Angular side too

```
initializeChannel() {
    
    this.routerSubscription =  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.storyFilterModel.channelId = params.channelId;
      this.channelName = decodeURI(params.channelName);
      this.storyFilterModel.pageSize = appConstants.POST_STORY_PAGESIZE;
      this.isFollowed = JSON.parse(params.isFollowed);
      if (!!params.lastVisitedDate && params.lastVisitedDate !== "null") {
        this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate = decodeURI(
          params.lastVisitedDate
        );
        this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate =
          this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate.includes("Z")
            ? this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate
            : this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate + ".000Z";
      } else {
        this.storyFilterModel.lastVisitedDate = new Date().toISOString();
      }
      this.channelService.updateChannelLastVisitDate(
        parseInt(params.channelId, 10)
      );
      this.channelService
        .getFollowedUsersList(params.channelId)
        .subscribe((result) => {
          this.channelService.followedUserList = result;
        });
    });
  }
```

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.initializeChannel();
    this.userService.setShowToolbar(false);
    this.currentUser = this.userService.userProfile;
    if (
      this.sharedService.getPreviousRoute() !== routeConstants.BUZZ_POST_URL &&
      this.sharedService.getPreviousRoute() !==
        routeConstants.BUZZ_ACTIVE_POST_STORIES_URL
    ) {
      this.resetOrLoadChannelAndPosts(true);
      this.sharedService.setIsPostEdit(false);
    } else {
      if (
        this.sharedService.getPreviousRoute() ===
        routeConstants.BUZZ_ACTIVE_POST_STORIES_URL
      ) {
        this.storyFilterModel.freeTextSearch = this.previousSearchText;
        this.storyFilterModel.page = this.channelService.allStoryListPageNumber;
        this.storyFilterModel.commentType = [];
        this.storyFilterModel.documentType = [];
      }
      if (this.storyFilterModel.freeTextSearch !== undefined && 
          this.storyFilterModel.freeTextSearch.trim().length > 2){
           this.setSearchedOrCacheResults(this.channelService.searchPostAndStoriesObj);
      } else {
           this.resetOrLoadChannelAndPosts(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

```
resetOrLoadChannelAndPosts(shouldMakeBackendCall, initializerObject?) {
   
    if (this.allPostAndStories.length === 0) {
      this.loading = true;
    }
    shouldMakeBackendCall =
      shouldMakeBackendCall &&
      !(
        this.channelService.NewPostData &&
        this.channelService.NewPostData.fileName.length > 0
      );
    this.channelPostsAndStoriesCacheObservable =
      this.loadChannelStoriesAndUserPostsFromCache(
        shouldMakeBackendCall
      ).subscribe((result) => {
        this.channelService.allPostAndStoriesObj = result;
        console.log("CallMap");
        this.mapChannelPostStoriesByTab(result, true, initializerObject);
      });
  }
```

```
  loadChannelStoriesAndUserPostsFromCache(shouldMakeBackendCall?) {
    const cacheKey = `ChannelStoriesAndUserPosts${this.storyFilterModel.channelId}`;
    const endpoint = this.loadChannelAndPostsCombined();
    const cacheModel = this.cacheUtilService.setCacheModel(cacheKey, endpoint);
    if (shouldMakeBackendCall) {
      return this.cacheUtilService.loadFromDelayedObservable(cacheModel);
    } else {
      return this.cacheUtilService.loadFromObservable(cacheModel);
    }
  }
```

```
 loadChannelAndPostsCombined() {
    return this.channelService
      .getChannelById(Number(this.storyFilterModel.channelId))
      .pipe(
        map((channelDetailsObject) => {
          this.setIsFollowedValue(channelDetailsObject);
          this.setStoryFilterModel(channelDetailsObject);
          this.updateChannelsPageCacheObject(channelDetailsObject);
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log("caught mapping error and rethrowing", err);
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate([routeConstants.BUZZ_CHANNELS_URL]);
            this.toasterNotification.errorMessage(
              appConstants.ACCESS_DENIED,
              toastConstants.POSITION_BOTTOM,
              3500
            );
          }
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.channelService.getChannelStoriesAndUserPosts(
            this.storyFilterModel
          )
        )
      );
  }
```

```
public getChannelStoriesAndUserPosts(storyFilterModel): Observable<any> {
    const allChannelStoriesAndUserPosts = this.getAllChannelStoriesAndUserPosts(storyFilterModel);
    const recentBuzzFilterMode = this.setRecentBuzzFilter(storyFilterModel);
    let allRecentBuzzStoryPost: any = [];
    if (storyFilterModel.page === 1 ){
        allRecentBuzzStoryPost = this.getAllChannelStoriesAndUserPosts(recentBuzzFilterMode);
    }
    return forkJoin([allChannelStoriesAndUserPosts, allRecentBuzzStoryPost]);
  }

  public getAllChannelStoriesAndUserPosts(storyFilterModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.httpPost(
      environment.buzzApiUrl + "channel/story/filter",
      storyFilterModel,
      {}
    );
  }
```

```
  mapChannelPostStoriesByTab(
    serviceResponse,
    resetStories = false,
    initializerObject = null
  ) {
    let allPostandStory: any = [];
    if (!!serviceResponse && serviceResponse.length > 1){
      allPostandStory = serviceResponse[0].searchResults;
      this.totalPostStoriesCount = serviceResponse[0].totalNumResults;
      this.totalActivePostStoriesCount = serviceResponse[1].totalNumResults;
    } else {
      allPostandStory = serviceResponse.searchResults;
    }
    this.channelService.cachedBackendResponse = allPostandStory;
    let newStories: ChannelPostStory[];
    let newActiveStories: ChannelPostStory[];
    if (resetStories) {
      //console.log("reset stories called");
      this.allPostAndStories = [];
      this.allActiveStoriesPost = [];
    }
    newStories = allPostandStory.filter(
      (ele) => ele.isNewItemPersist !== false
    );
    newStories.forEach((listElement) => {
      if (listElement.documentType === appConstants.USERPOST) {
        if (!listElement.userAvatarImageLink) {
          listElement.imageLoader = true;
        }
        this.getAvatarImage(listElement);
      }
    });
    this.allPostAndStories.push(...newStories);
    if (!!serviceResponse && serviceResponse.length > 1){
      newActiveStories = serviceResponse[1].searchResults.filter(
        (ele) => ele.isNewItemPersist !== false
      );
      newActiveStories.forEach((listElement) => {
        if (listElement.documentType === appConstants.USERPOST) {
          if (!listElement.userAvatarImageLink) {
            listElement.imageLoader = true;
          }
          this.getAvatarImage(listElement);
        }
      });
      this.allActiveStoriesPost.push(...newActiveStories);
  }
    this.addChannelPostOnUI();
    if (
      initializerObject &&
      initializerObject.type.toLowerCase() ===
        ionicComponentsConstants.ION_REFERESH
    ) {
      initializerObject.target.complete();
    }
    if (
      initializerObject &&
      initializerObject.type.toLowerCase() ===
        ionicComponentsConstants.ION_INFINITE
    ) {
      initializerObject.target.complete();
      if (this.allPostAndStories.length >= this.totalPostStoriesCount) {
        initializerObject.target.disabled = true;
      }
    }
    if (this.allPostAndStories.length >= this.totalPostStoriesCount) {
      if (this.infiniteScroll) {
        this.infiniteScroll.disabled = false;
      }
    }
    if (
      this.sharedService.getPreviousRoute() === routeConstants.BUZZ_POST_URL ||
      this.sharedService.getPreviousRoute() ===
        routeConstants.BUZZ_ACTIVE_POST_STORIES_URL
    ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollToPreviousPosition();
      }, 0);
      this.sharedService.setPreviousRoute("");
    }
    this.channelService.setAllPostStoriesList(this.allPostAndStories);
    //this.filterStoriesForActiveTab(this.allPostAndStories);
    //console.log("active array:-", this.activePostAndStories);
    //console.log("all array:-", this.allPostAndStories);
    const IsPostEdit = this.sharedService.getIsPostEdit();
    if (IsPostEdit) {
      this.editPostOnUI(this.channelService.PostMetadata.uniqueID);
    }
    this. Loading = false;
  }
```

Now if someone has this much time then please look at the HTML also

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="warning">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <!-- <ion-button>hjgjg</ion-button> -->
       <ion-back-button text="" defaultHref="/tabs/buzz/channels"  color="dark">
      </ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{channelName}}</ion-title>
    <ion-icon
      [hidden]="!isFollowed"
      class="fb"
      src="assets/icon/followed.svg"
      (click)="toggleFollow()"
    ></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon
      [hidden]="isFollowed"
      class="fb"
      src="assets/icon/unfollowed.svg"
      (click)="toggleFollow()"
    ></ion-icon>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="warning">
    <ion-searchbar
      color="light"
      #postsSearchBar
      placeholder="Search Stories & Posts"
      enterkeyhint = "go"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
      [(ngModel)]="storyFilterModel.freeTextSearch"
      (search)="searchTextChange($event)"
      (ionClear)="clearSearchText()"
      (click)="setFocusOnSearchBar()"
      (focusout)="onSearchFocusOut()"
    >
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<app-loading [loading]="loading"></app-loading>
<ion-content
  [scrollEvents]="true"
  (ionScrollStart)="removeFocusFromSearchBar()"
  *ngIf="!loading"
>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="refreshPostAndStories($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-down"></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <section>
    <ion-row class="bottom-border">
      <ion-col class="heading" size="12">
        <ion-label class="label-size">RECENT BUZZ</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row
      class="bottom-border ion-no-padding"
      *ngFor="let post of allActiveStoriesPost; let index = index;" 
      [hidden] = "index > 2"
      (click)="navgiateToPost(post)"
    >
      <ion-col [size]="post.uniqueID === undefined ? 8.5 : 9.5">
        <ion-avatar class="user-img" *ngIf="post.documentType === 'userpost'">
          <ion-skeleton-text
            animated
            *ngIf="post.imageLoader"
          ></ion-skeleton-text>
          <img [hidden]="post.imageLoader" [src]="post.userAvatarImageLink" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='userpost'"
          >{{post.fullname}}
        </ion-text>
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='userpost'"
          >/ {{post.uploadDate | timeago:live}}
        </ion-text>
        <!--DO NOT REMOVE THIS CODE: this code needs to be added later-->
        <!-- <app-swot [size]="'medium'" *ngIf="post.documentType=='story'"></app-swot> -->
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='story'"
          >{{post.postedBy}} / {{post.uploadDate | timeago:live}}</ion-text
        >
        <br />
        <!-- /*** TODO: Use padding/margin styling instead of BR tag ***/ -->
        <ion-label>
          <div [innerHtml]="post.fileName"></div>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col [size]="post.uniqueID === undefined ? 1 : 0">
        <ion-spinner
          name="lines"
          *ngIf="post.uniqueID === undefined"
        ></ion-spinner>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="comments" size="2.5">
        <ion-icon
          [class.yellow-bubble]="post.comments.newCommentsRepliesSinceLastVisit"
          *ngIf="(post.comments.totalComments > 0||post.comments.newCommentsRepliesSinceLastVisit)"
          src="assets/icon/text.svg"
          class="ion-align-self-start"
        ></ion-icon>
        <ion-label
          *ngIf="post.comments.totalComments > 0"
          class="count ion-align-self-start"
        >
          {{post.comments.totalComments}}</ion-label
        >
        <!--chevron icon-->
        <ion-icon
          name="chevron-forward-outline"
          class="arrow-position"
        ></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngIf="!!allActiveStoriesPost && allActiveStoriesPost.length >0" class="more-button">
      <ion-label class="all-buzz-btn" color="primary" (click)="navigateToRecentlyActiveView()"
        >All the Buzz
        <ion-icon size="small" name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngIf="allActiveStoriesPost.length === 0">
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-label *ngIf="!searchStarted" color="dark" class="wrap-text"
          >No recent posts or comments.
        </ion-label>
        <ion-label *ngIf="searchStarted" color="dark" class="wrap-text"
          >No search results found.</ion-label
        >
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </section>
  <section>
    <ion-row class="bottom-border">
      <ion-col class="heading" size="12">
        <ion-label class="label-size">ALL STORIES AND POSTS</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row
      class="bottom-border ion-no-padding"
      *ngFor="let post of allPostAndStories"
      (click)="navgiateToPost(post)"
    >
      <ion-col [size]="post.uniqueID === undefined ? 8.5 : 9.5">
        <ion-avatar class="user-img" *ngIf="post.documentType === 'userpost'">
          <ion-skeleton-text
            animated
            *ngIf="post.imageLoader"
          ></ion-skeleton-text>
          <img [hidden]="post.imageLoader" [src]="post.userAvatarImageLink" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='userpost'"
          >{{post.fullname}}
        </ion-text>
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='userpost'"
          >/ {{post.uploadDate | timeago:live}}
        </ion-text>
        <!--DO NOT REMOVE THIS CODE: this code needs to be added later-->
        <!-- <app-swot [size]="'medium'" *ngIf="post.documentType=='story'"></app-swot> -->
        <ion-text class="posted-info-text" *ngIf="post.documentType=='story'"
          >{{post.postedBy}} / {{post.uploadDate | timeago:live}}</ion-text
        >
        <br />
        <!-- /*** TODO: Use padding/margin styling instead of BR tag ***/ -->
        <ion-label>
          <div [innerHtml]="post.fileName"></div>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col [size]="post.uniqueID === undefined ? 1 : 0">
        <ion-spinner
          name="lines"
          *ngIf="post.uniqueID === undefined"
        ></ion-spinner>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="comments" size="2.5">
        <ion-icon
          [class.yellow-bubble]="post.comments.newCommentsRepliesSinceLastVisit"
          *ngIf="(post.comments.totalComments > 0||post.comments.newCommentsRepliesSinceLastVisit)"
          src="assets/icon/text.svg"
          class="ion-align-self-start"
        ></ion-icon>
        <ion-label
          *ngIf="post.comments.totalComments > 0"
          class="count ion-align-self-start"
        >
          {{post.comments.totalComments}}</ion-label
        >
        <!--chevron icon-->
        <ion-icon
          name="chevron-forward-outline"
          class="arrow-position"
        ></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngIf="!!allPostAndStories && allPostAndStories.length === 0">
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-label *ngIf="!searchStarted" color="dark" class="wrap-text"
          >No recent posts or comments.
        </ion-label>
        <ion-label *ngIf="searchStarted" color="dark" class="wrap-text"
          >No search results found.</ion-label
        >
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-infinite-scroll class="ion-padding-vertical"
      threshold="10%"
      (ionInfinite)="loadChannelStoriesAndUserPost($event,false)"
      #infiniteScroll
    >
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        loadingSpinner="lines"
        loadingText="Loading more ..."
      >
      </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </section>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer *ngIf="!loading && !isKeyboardActive" [style.opacity]="loading ? '0.7' : '1'">
  <ion-toolbar class="channel-view-footer" (click)="newPost()">
    <ion-icon name="create" class="new-post-icon v-middle"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label class="v-middle">New Post</ion-label>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

As soon as the application makes an request to the API, it takes ages to load the data even though the Data is retured from the Redis Cache. can someone please suggest what might be the problem???

Comment: If you say that you can see in the network tab that the data is already received, but it looks like its still loading sounds like me you have a change detection issue. Is the componet that loads using change detection strategy onPush. If so try to turn it off to see loads fast. Though i do recommend using onPush.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Revise how the flow needs to be.

Comment: @StackoverBlows can you please suggest what is wrong here. I'm really kind of stuck with this issue